# How to get and draw multiple path between two location using google distance api?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-directory-api

I am working on a project in which, user chooses two location and i have to show multiple path between chosen location.

FYI :-  Currently i am able to find a single path and draw them, I am using this link to find single path to draw https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=28.629074,77.37911&destination=28.459496499999997,77.0266383&sensor=false&alternative=true&mode=driving

Please suggest us how to find multiple path to draw.

Thank You.

Comment: I did it, What i was doing wrong is my URL was containing "alternative=true" while it has to be  "alternative=true". 

Such a stupid mistake.

Comment: is it still working for you ? as i m trying your url with 'alternative=true' i am still getting a single route.

Comment: Hi, Sorry for typo, it's `alternatives=true`. You can find details here [google direction api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it, What i was doing wrong is my URL was containing 
    "alternative=true" 
while it has to be 
    "alternatives=true"
Such a stupid mistake.